# Oracle overlapping dates

Tags: oracle, date, overlap, overlapping

Oracle 10g

There are two payment graphs:

```
OPER_ID  PAYDATE
1        09.12.2013
1        13.01.2014
1        08.02.2014
1        11.03.2014
1        08.04.2014
...................
1        07.11.2018
2        08.04.2014
2        08.05.2014
2        09.06.2014
```

In some cases there may be more graphs. How can i overlap this graphs so, that first ends when second starts? Something like this:

```
OPER_ID  PAYDATE
1        09.12.2013
1        13.01.2014
1        08.02.2014
1        11.03.2014  
2        08.04.2014
2        08.05.2014
2        09.06.2014
```

In help i've table with date of operation:

```
OPER_ID  OPER_DATE
1        07.11.2013
2        11.03.2014
```

**UPDATE**

1. Graphs are in one table
2. Dates in the graphs are mostly identical

Comment: Do you simply want to sort the data by paydate? Something like ... select oper_id, paydate from <graph_table> order by paydate;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your payment graphs are stored in `GRAPH1` and `GRAPH2` tables, I can offer solution:

```
SELECT 
 x.paydate,
 g1.operid as g1_operid,
 g2.operid as g2_operid
FROM (
      SELECT 
         t.paydate
      FROM (SELECT paydate FROM graph1 UNION ALL SELECT paydate FROM graph2) t
      GROUP BY t.paydate
) x
LEFT JOIN graph1 g1 ON g1.paydate = x.paydate
LEFT JOIN graph1 g2 ON g2.paydate = x.paydate
ORDER BY x.paydate
```

The idea is to select an unique set of dates in both graphs, then join graphs by paydate.

Comment: I've updated my question. There is only one table with graphs. And dates in graphs are not unique, in most cases they are identical

Comment: Ok, then change graph2 to graph1, and change (SELECT paydate FROM graph1 UNION ALL SELECT paydate FROM graph2) to graph1 and you'll got it.